# C# async Tasks - assign a int to every task based on its order

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

Program deletes two large zip files if exists, download new zips and finally extract it with some tasks done parallelly.
Each task prints description of the task to console when the task is triggered.

Now I also want to print number together with description - number to be incremented by 1 each time any of the tasks is completed.

For this I have declared variable in the main method `int x = 1;`
I made every task to return a int. 
`Task<int>`  returns integer `x` incremented by `1`. `( Return ++x; )`

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
     string sZip = @" some path ";
     string fZip = @" some path ";
     string sFolder = @" some path ";
     string fFolder = @" some path ";

     int x = 1;

     // Tasks to do
     x = await FirstZipDelete(x, sZip); 

     var sequence2 = new List<Task> { FirstZipDownload(x, sZip), SecondZipDelete(x, fZip) };
     await Task.WhenAll(sequence2); 

     var sequence3 = new List<Task> { SecondZipDownload(x, fZip), 
     FirstZipExtract(x, sZip, sFolder) };
     await Task.WhenAll(sequence3); 

     x = await SecondZipExtract(x, fZip, fFolder);
```

By putting `x =`  before single tasks I achieved incrementing of the integer. 
But same could not be applied for parallel tasks. 
 
 Any idea to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand is that you first delete the old file, then download and extract. If the deletion/download/extract are always sequential for one file. You should put them into one task.

A problem you have is that the `x` is not threadsafe, so you would sometimes see that the sequence is not perfect.

You need to lock `x`, I've used the `Interlocked.Increment()` for this.

I don't know if I understand the *"Now I also want to print number together with description - number to be incremented by 1 each time any of the tasks is completed."* correctly. As my solution combines some "tasks". The trick is to use the return value which `Interlocked.Increment` returns to captured the incremented value. You won't mis any numbers this way, because incrementing/storing (and so return that incremented value) is atomic.

Something like:

```
string sZip = @" some path ";
string fZip = @" some path ";
string sFolder = @" some path ";
string fFolder = @" some path ";

var tasks = new List<Task>();

// You should start at -1 (because I increment it before the task was executed)
int x = -1;

tasks.Add(Task.Run(async () =>
{
    int xValue = Interlocked.Increment(ref x);
    await FirstZipDelete(xValue, sZip);

    xValue = Interlocked.Increment(ref x);
    await FirstZipDownload(xValue, sZip);

    xValue = Interlocked.Increment(ref x);
    await FirstZipExtract(xValue, sZip, sFolder);
}));

tasks.Add(Task.Run(async () =>
{
    int xValue = Interlocked.Increment(ref x);
    await FirstZipDelete(xValue, fZip);

    xValue = Interlocked.Increment(ref x);
    await FirstZipDownload(xValue, fZip);

    xValue = Interlocked.Increment(ref x);
    await FirstZipExtract(xValue, fZip, fFolder);
}));

await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

---

Some small modifications and it might look like this:

```
string sZip = @" some path ";
string fZip = @" some path ";
string sFolder = @" some path ";
string fFolder = @" some path ";

var tasks = new List<Task>();

int x = 0;

async Task DownloadAndExtract(string zip, string folder)
{
    int xValue = Interlocked.Increment(ref x);
    await FirstZipDelete(xValue, zip);

    xValue = Interlocked.Increment(ref x);
    await FirstZipDownload(xValue, zip);

    xValue = Interlocked.Increment(ref x);
    await FirstZipExtract(xValue, zip, folder);
}

await Task.WhenAll(
    DownloadAndExtract(sZip, sFolder),
    DownloadAndExtract(fZip, fFolder));
```

Comment: Hi Jeroen, if I fire two tasks DownloadAndExtract in parallel (for two zips) they start to download at same time. I want to download first zip to run processes on it while second zip will be downloading. Because for time savings, I need to run SecondZipDownload and FirstZipExtract in parallel.